# Дистрибуция - дистрибьюция, дистрибутор - дистрибьютор

Tags: орфография, фразеология, переводы

Читал массу вариантов/дискуссий как со стороны лингвистов, так собственно и самих г-д дистрибьюторов (коих в наших пределах предостаточно) о правильности/неправильности слов:

- *дистрибьюция* или *дистрибуция*
- *дистрибутор* или *дистрибьютор*

Я лично предпочитаю пару: *дистрибьютор* и *дистрибуция*

Comment: По Вашему получаются как бы не однокоренные слова.

Comment: "Читал массу вариантов/дискуссий как со стороны лингвистов, так собственно и самих г-д дистрибьюторов" Ну так и поделитесь,пожалуйста,  что именно лингвисты думают по этому поводу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"На слух" эти варианты действительно приятнее двух других. Но вопрос единообразия никак нельзя сбрасывать со счетов.

Но вообще-то прежде всего надо руководствоваться рекомендациями словарей, иначе вопрос о правильности терят всякий смысл. А словари в большинстве своём дают два варианта для "дистрибьютора"/"дистрибутора" и только один для "дистрибуция".

Присоединяюсь к пожеланию озакомиться с ходом и результатами упомянутых дискуссий.

Comment: Версия лингвистов звучала так:

  1. Можно писать и так и эдак
  2. Другая версия, как бы более правильно: *дистрибьютор/дистрибуция*, дескать при образовании *дистрибуция* происходит нечто вроде чередования с "проглатыванием" мягкого знака

Версия дистрибьюторов: в начале 90-х общепринятой была версия *дистрибутор/дистрибуция* (в американизированном произношении), сейчас *дистрибьютор/дистрибьюция*

Comment: Если принять вариант *дистрибьюция*, то логично, что есть слово *КОНТРИБУЦИЯ*? По-моему, нет. Тогда лучше сделать все однообразно =)

Comment: Еще вариант помимо *дистрибутор* или *дистрибьютор* - *дистрибьютер*. Но он мне нравится еще меньше, если честно.